# Add ... to complete sentence in jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Minor nitpick, initially at the bottom of the jobs section there is a:

> Hang on, there is more!  Click here to see fresh jobs

Can we change it to:

> Hang on, there is more!  Click here to see fresh jobs...

Only because `Hang on, there is more!` is a complete valid sentence with punctuation I only think it's fair!

Here's the image:

[image]

Comment: What about "Hang on, [there are more fresh jobs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316667/4151918)!"

Comment: @PetahChristian Fine with me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. This has been updated to "Hang on, there are more fresh jobs!" You'll see the change in the next prod build.